# Deep Reverse in PROLOG - Lists

Tags: prolog, nested-lists, declarative-programming, prolog-defaulty

Hey I'm trying to create a predicate for the generating of a deep reverse on nested Lists in PROLOG.

Currently I got this predicate

```
reverse(L,A) :- rev(L,[], A).
rev([],A,A).
rev([H|L],R,A) :- rev(L,[H|R],A).
```

The result looks like this:

```
reverse([1,2,3],A).
A = [3, 2, 1].

reverse([[0,1],2,3],A).
A = [3, 2, [0, 1]].
```

The problem is, that the inner List is not reversed. It should look like this:

```
reverse([[0,1],2,3],A).
A = [3, 2, [1, 0]].

reverse([1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7],8],[9,10],11,12],A).
A = [12,11,[10,9],[8,[7,6],5,4,3],2,1].
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things as simple as possible, we could add a test if the current element being checked is a list or not. If it is indeed a list, then its elements should be reversed as well. So in code:

```
my_reverse(L,R) :- rev(L,[],R).

rev([],A,A).
rev([H|T],A,R) :-
    ( is_list(H) ->        % If H is a list
      rev(H,[],X),         %   then reverse H as well
      rev(T,[X|A],R)
    ;
      rev(T,[H|A],R)
    ).
```

Also, not that it really matters, just to try and avoid confusion, note how I used `A` and `R` for respectively `Accumulator` and `Result`. In your code they are currently swapped, which -for me personally- can be a bit confusing, especially when predicates become longer and more complex.

Anyway, let's look at the queries you provided:

```
?- my_reverse([[0,1],2,3],R).
R = [3, 2, [1, 0]].

?- my_reverse([1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7],8],[9,10],11,12],R).
R = [12, 11, [10, 9], [8, [7, 6], 5, 4, 3], 2, 1].
```

And some general queries:

```
?- my_reverse(L,R).
L = R, R = [] ;
L = R, R = [_G2437] ;
L = [_G2437, _G2443],
R = [_G2443, _G2437] ;
L = [_G2437, _G2443, _G2449],
R = [_G2449, _G2443, _G2437] ;
L = [_G2437, _G2443, _G2449, _G2455],
R = [_G2455, _G2449, _G2443, _G2437] 
...

?- my_reverse([[X,Y]|T],R), member(a,T), length(X,2).
X = [_G2588, _G2591],
T = [a],
R = [a, [Y, [_G2588, _G2591]]]
;
X = [_G2594, _G2597],
T = [a, _G2588],
R = [_G2588, a, [Y, [_G2594, _G2597]]]
;
X = [_G2594, _G2597],
T = [_G2582, a],
R = [a, _G2582, [Y, [_G2594, _G2597]]]
...
```

Note however that using this predicate, no termination occurs after finding the first answer to the query:

```
?- my_reverse(X,[X]).
X = [X] ;
...
```

But since this wasn't a requirement/demand in OP's question, I assumed it to be okay.

**EDIT:**

Please read [@mat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38632059/1153801) as a follow-up to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

The way you represent your data is called **defaulty**, because you need a *default* case when reasoning over it:

- is it a list? → something holds
- **otherwise** → something else holds.

Such a representation is a rich source of troubles. Consider for example `my_reverse/2` from the other answer. The main problem with it is that it prematurely and *incorrectly* **commits** to one of the cases, although *both* cases are still possible:

```
?- my_reverse([X], Ls).
Ls = [X].
```

But this answer only holds for the case where `X` is **not** a list! This problem leads to the following strange behaviour of the predicate:

```
?- my_reverse([X], Ls), X = [1,2,3].
Ls = [[1, 2, 3]],
X = [1, 2, 3].
```

This mean that even though `X` is a list, its elements are *not* reversed!

You should always aim for cleaner representations to distinguish the cases that can arise.

For example, what would you say about the following way to represent your data:

- `list(Ls)` represents the **list** `Ls`
- `n(N)` represents the **number** `N`.

With such a representations, we can distinguish the cases symbolically. I leave this as the starting point for a more declarative solution.

Answer (score 0):

an additional solution for your problem is to use cut and the built-in predicate "is_list/1" to check if you treat a simple term or a list in the current call.
here is the code:

```
deepReverse(List,R):-deepReverseTail(List,[],R).

deepReverseTail([],Acc,Acc).

deepReverseTail([H|T],Acc,R):-             % when H is a list
     is_list(H),                           % check if it's a list.
     !,                                    % cut the process if not. 
     deepReverseTail(H,[],Hrev),           % reverse this current list
     deepReverseTail(T,[Hrev|Acc],R).      % continue the general recursion

deepReverseTail([H|T],Acc,R):- deepReverseTail(T,[H|Acc],R). % when H is a simple term
```

the "cut" in the third line make sure you treat only list in this definition, while treating simple terms will be in the next definitions.

an output example:

```
7 ?- deepReverse([a,[d,f],[],[[k],g]],R)
R = [[g, [k]], [], [f, d], a].
```